# Firebase PubSub functions take over 2 minutes to respond

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a firebase function which receives webhooks. This works 100% and returns 200 to the provider. The function looks as follows (It's been simplified):

```js
export const webhook = https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
    const pubsub = new PubSub({ projectId: process.env.GCLOUD_PROJECT });

    const usersToUpdate = [
        'uid1',
        'uid2',
        'uid3',
    ];

    await Promise.all(usersToUpdate.map(user => {
        pubsub.topic('myTopic').publishJSON({ userId: user.id })
    }));

    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The PubSub function looks as follows:

```js
export const updateUsers = runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 540 }).pubsub.topic('myTopic').onPublish(async (message) => {
    const { userID } = message.json;
    await updateMyUsers(userID);
});
```

The functions work, the only problem is that the `updateUsers` takes over two minutes to receive the topic (get triggered).

My understanding is that PubSub should take a few seconds max to receive. Is there a way to speed it up?

Comment: Why are you using pubsub and not firestore to update users?

Comment: The function `updateMyUsers` has the functionality to do some requests based on the `userId` and then updates firestore accordingly

Comment: Maybe the location of your function is to far away. Are you using us-central1?

Comment: By time taken to "receive the topic", do you mean time taken for `updateUsers()` to be called and returned? How long does it take for `updateMyUsers()` to complete?

Comment: @TimeString yes, time taken for `updateUsers()` to be called. The function completes in the expected time.

Comment: It’s still not clear where the 2-min delay comes from. There are a few events that I’m interested in: (1)When `await Promise.all(usersToUpdate...` is called, (2) when the callback of `.onPublish()` is called, and (3) when the same callback completes. If the delay comes from (1)-(2), then the issue is likely slow publishing to PubSub. If it's from (2)-(3), then it's likely from `updateMyUsers()`. If I understand your response correctly, (2)-(3) is good. Can you confirm that (1)-(2) is causing the delay? If so, you may want to open a case with cloud support with the details of your PubSub topic.

Comment: @TimeString Yes, the delay is from (1)-(2). From what I've read is that PubSub seems to prefer more volume but a delay of 2 minutes is very slow.

Comment: TimeString is right, it seems like it is better to open a case with GCP to they look into your logs and CF and Pub/Sub settings